# getting file.getDownloadUrl() as null even i have tried scope as DriveScopes.DRIVE_READONLY and DriveScopes.all()

Tags: java, image-processing, google-drive-api

I have used both DriveScopes.DRIVE_READONLY and DriveScopes.all() but still I am getting 
file.getDownloadUrl() as null.

```
private final static Collection<String> scopes=DriveScopes.all(); 

InputStream in=null;
if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
HttpResponse resp = drive.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new 
GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl())).execute();
inputStrem = resp.getContent();
}
```

Comment: What API version are you using, v2 or v3? Also, what kind of file it is?

Comment: I am using v2. even I have used v3. It is a image file 
OutputStream out=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
drive.files().export(file.getId(), "image/jpeg").executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);
and
drive.files().get(file.getId()).executeAndDownloadTo(out);
it didn't work

Comment: `downloadUrl` is only populated for non-Google Documents. Did you get this image using [Drawings](https://docs.google.com/drawings/)? Have you checked whether the resource contains any `exportLinks`?